# Clearing Interval from another function problems

Tags: javascript, function, clearinterval

Good morning, i have some problems with clearing intervals.
Here is my example of code:

```js
const count = document.getElementById('count');
let didStart = false;
let countingNumber = 1;

function startCounting(number) {
  setInterval(() => {
    const getNumber = parseInt(count.innerText);
    count.innerText = getNumber + number;
  }, 1000)
}

function resetCounting() {
    didStart = false;
  countingNumber = 2;
  console.log('DID START', didStart);
  // IT SHOULD CLEAR INTERVAL FROM START COUNTING FUNCTION, HERE
}

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click', resetCounting);

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (!didStart && !event.target.classList.contains('reset')) {
        didStart = true;
      console.log('DID START', didStart);
      switch (event.target.dataset.name) {
        case 'test-1':
          startCounting(countingNumber);
        break;
        case 'test-2':
          startCounting(2)
        break;
      }
    }
    
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <button data-name="test-1">
    START 1
  </button>
  <button data-name="test-2">
    START 2
  </button>
  <button id="reset" class="reset">
    Reset
  </button>
  <p id="count">
    0
  </p>
</div>
```

**Reproducing problem:**

1. Click on `Start 1`
2. Click on `Reset`
3. Click on `Start 1` one more time

It schould clear Interval in function resetCounting and begin to count with new value.
I don't know how to resolve this problem. Any help with understending this thing will be greatfull!

Comment: When you call `setInterval()` you need to store the returned value in a variable, and pass that variable to `clearInterval()` later.

Comment: Ok, i understand that, what about React, when this function to setInterval will be in another file (context) and reset will be called from another file?

Comment: You'll have to store the interval ID in a shared parent scope - e.g. a parent component, Redux store, or use a React context.

Comment: Interval id? What do you mean?

Comment: When you call `setInterval()` it returns an interval ID.